# ULEB128 variable-length integer encoding

Tags: parsing, d

I'm trying to write a ULEB 128 parser that will take an array of unsigned bytes and return the value and shift required. If understand correctly if I have a `ubyte[] list = [0x1b, 0x02, 0x03]` then what I do is look at the `0x1b` and here the high bit is greater than `0`, so then I've to read the next byte. In the end it should return `0x20b` with a shift of 2 without including `0x03`, as the second byte high bit is `0`. If my logic is correct, my main issue is byte manipulation in D i.e. how to check the high or low bits.

Comment: The high bit of 0x1b is 0. (It's 0b0001011).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If my logic is correct, my main issue is byte manipulation in D i.e. how to check the high or low bits.

Like you would do in C. You can use bitwise and (`&`) and binary shift (`<<`).
If you need an example to go by, druntime does this:
https://github.com/dlang/druntime/blob/0dfc0ce5aef1fde00713b56e9be99dcdfb04d171/src/rt/backtrace/dwarf.d#L490-L534

Comment: Thank you. I ended up modifying this function in order to also return the consumed bytes, but it works.